# Accessing the screen width and height in CSS Media Queries?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Is it possible to access the screen's width and height in CSS Media queries, to write a dynamic url, like this:

```
@media all
{
    background: url("http://site.com/background/" + width + "/" + height");
}
```

Here width and height are variables, which would be dynamically set to whatever the user's width and height is.

Is that possible, or do I have to use javascript to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. CSS does not know anything about the environment.

Comment: As an aside, you might like to look into a CSS framework like SASS - while it still doesn't know the window size, it does allow you to set variables and use them throughout the stylesheet as you have indicated.